# Why isn't my custom errorbar function working in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, ggplot2, visualization

I have tried to make a function to quickly make an error bar based on a grouping factor and a numerical value as defined below:

```
#### Function ####
quick.error <- function(data,x,y){
  d <- data
  plot.d <- d %>%
    mutate(x = as.factor(x)) %>% 
    group_by(x) %>%
    summarise(
      sd = sd(y, na.rm = TRUE),
      mean = mean(y, na.rm=TRUE)
    ) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x, 
               mean,
               fill=x)) +
    geom_col(color = "black") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-sd,
                      ymax = mean+sd),
                  width = 0.2) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
  return(plot.d)
}
```

However, when I try to run this with the `iris` dataset:

```
#### Test ####
quick.error(data=iris,
            x=Species,
            y=Petal.Length)
```

This gives me an error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `x = as.factor(x)`.
Caused by error in `is.factor()`:
! object 'Species' not found
```

Running it explicitly with `$` operators gives me a different issue:

```
#### Test ####
quick.error(data=iris,
            x=iris$Species,
            y=iris$Petal.Length)
```

As you can see here, it has made all the bars the same, I assume because it did not group the mean like it was supposed to:

[image]

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of non-standard evaluation ([NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)) in the tidyverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I indicate in my comment, this is a typical non-standard evaluation problem.  Here's a revised function that I believe gives you what you want.

```
quick.error <- function(data,x,y){
  d <- data
  plot.d <- d %>%
    mutate({{ x }} := as.factor({{ x }})) %>% 
    group_by({{ x }}) %>%
    summarise(
      sd = sd({{ y }}, na.rm = TRUE),
      mean = mean({{ y }}, na.rm=TRUE)
    ) %>% 
    ggplot(aes({{ x }}, 
               mean,
               fill={{ x }})) +
    geom_col(color = "black") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-sd,
                      ymax = mean+sd),
                  width = 0.2) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
  return(plot.d)
}

quick.error(data=iris,
            x=Species,
            y=Petal.Length)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this was a very straightforward answer and I appreciate the link share.

Answer (score 2):

Passing unquoted column names to a function

> ... requires injection with the embracing operator {{ or, in more complex cases, the injection operator !!.

For more on that see e.g. [this vignette](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask.html).

Hence you could make your function work by wrapping `x` and `y` inside your function in `{{`:

```r
quick.error <- function(data, x, y) {
  d <- data
  plot.d <- d %>%
    mutate(x = as.factor({{ x }})) %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    summarise(
      sd = sd({{ y }}, na.rm = TRUE),
      mean = mean({{ y }}, na.rm = TRUE)
    ) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x,
      mean,
      fill = x
    )) +
    geom_col(color = "black") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(
      ymin = mean - sd,
      ymax = mean + sd
    ),
    width = 0.2
    ) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")

  return(plot.d)
}

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

quick.error(
  data = iris,
  x = Species,
  y = Petal.Length
)
```

[image]